# Compiz extra animations download Ubuntu 14.04 not working ( burning animations ETC)

Tags: compiz, 14.04, animations

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Latitude yesterday. I wanted some cool window animations so I installed CompizConfig and also (at least, that is what I have tried to do), installed the extra animations that are available. I used the terminal with the following command to install the extra package:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

When I finally had set up everything, I wanted to use a burning effect on the closing animation,however, I couldn't even find that animation in the list!
What I have seen is that I have to turn on *Animation addon* to use those animations, but I don't have that option.

Is there any way to get the extra effects on compiz with Ubuntu 14.04? Or are the effects removed because they were unstable?

Comment: I have the same problem. The compiz-plugins-extra seems to be a dummy transitional package.

Comment: The compiz-plugins-extra package has been dropped from support for stability. AFAIK there is no plan to bring it back, so you have to leave without it unless someone is determined to rewrite from the old package to adapt for Unity.

Answer (score 2):

The Compiz-plugins-extra is more or less an empyty package. To get the "extra" options you need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
```

Because CCSM only installs the package named compiz-plugins-default (or defaults, don't remember)